# Accessing external variables from inside a @foreach loop

Tags: javascript, linq, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I am struggling with using variables in JavaScript in an MVC view. I have code that I use to handle the View Model objects and extracting the count using a linq query, but in order to do so, I have to use a `@foreach` loop in my JavaScript. I then need to use the result of my loop outside to make a graph out of it.
Here is my loop:

```
function getCount()
{        
    var counta = 0;

    @foreach (var item in Model.AccountList)
    {
        var listCount = @Model.List.Where(s => s.Id == 1).Count();
        counta += listCount;                           
    }
};
```

I would like to know how can I use the `counta` variable inside the foreach loop or declare a static variable that is accessed inside the loop and when going out of the loop keeps it's value.

Comment: You may need to look into closures...

Comment: "i would like to know how can i use the 'counta' variable inside the foreach loop!!" You already are.... you are appending listCount to it in the loop. Do you mean you want to access "counta" outside the scope of the getCount() function?

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model.AccountList)` is razor code which is evaluated on the server before its sent to the client `counta` is a client side javascript variable which does not even exist at that point (its not in scope)

Comment: yeah but the 'counta' variable is not in the scope of the @foreach loop. that variable is not accessible from within the loop.

Comment: It must be? What is the value of "counta" if you do console.log(counta) while inside that loop? Is it undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused because you have mixed JS and ASP.NET variables.
The **code within `foreach` is** always interpreted **as C# code**

```
function getCount() // JS function
{        
    var counta = 0; // JS variable

    @foreach (var item in Model.AccountList) // C# loop
    {
        var listCount = @Model.List.Where(s=> s.Id  ==1).Count(); // C# variable
        // here, you are trying to add C# integer to JavaScript variable. it is impossible
        counta += listCount;  
    }
}
```

**How to solve this**: Calculate it server-side and simply output it in JavaScript:

```
@{ // It's all C# code
    var count = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model.AccountList)
    {
        var listCount = Model.List.Where(s=> s.Id == 1).Count();
        count += listCount;                           
    }
}

<script>
    var counta = @(count); // JS counta variable is equal to C# calculated "count"
    console.log(counta);
</script>
```

It will become:

```
<script>
    var counta = 17; // for example
    console.log(counta);
</script>
```

For every generated page it will be a constant.

Comment: THANKS A LOOOOOT!!!! i have searched several pages in order to find a solution .. and FINALLY it was as simple as that ... @YeldarKurmangaliyev i will find u .. and i will give a biiiig hug thanks man :D